# enum datatype default number assignment

Tags: objective-c, enums

to what numbers (if any) do Jan, Feb, Mar map if I just write code like this:

```
enum months {Jan, Feb, Mar};
```

but not explicitly give them corresponding numbers like in this case:

```
enum months {Jan=1, Feb, Mar};
```

Comment: maybe you have to start with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the first element in a list is set equal to 0, and each subsequent element is assigned a value one greater.  Therefore in your first:

```
enum months {Jan, Feb, Mar};
```

Jan = 0, Feb = 1, Mar = 2

In your second:

```
enum months {Jan=1, Feb, Mar};
```

Jan=1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3

[Reference 1](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/objectivec-lesson-7-enumerated-types-and-typedefs/72)

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832606/objective-c-c-giving-enums-default-values)